# Linear approximation measure?

Tags: calculus, linear-approximation

The problem: given any $F(x)$ and a point $P_1$, and an $\Delta \gt 0$, find an $P_2$ such that $L(x)$ is a straight line crossing both points which meets the requirement: $|F(x) - L(x)| \lt \Delta$ for any $x \in [P_1; P_2]$. So, in other words, all I have to do is to approximate any function with a linear fellow such that an error for any points belonging an interval is less than predefined value.

My attempt to solve the problem:
$$L(x) = a * x + b$$
$$ a =\frac{P_{2y} - P_{1y}}{P_{2x} - P_{1x}}$$
Since both points are shared by $F(x)$ and $L(x)$:
$$ P_{2y} = F(P_{2x}) $$
As such:
$$ L(x) = \frac{F(P_{2x}) - F(P_{1x})}{P_{2x} - P_{1x}} * x + b $$
Which allows to reformulate the original formula above:
$$\forall x \in [P_1; P_2] : |F(x) - \frac{F(P_{2x}) - F(P_{1x})}{P_{2x} - P_{1x}} * x - b| \lt \Delta$$

Since $P_1$ is predefined, I have to rewrite given inequality such that it gives me something like $P_{2x} \lt V$ where $V$ is some kind of positive value?

The question is: am I making things more complicated than they naturally are and is there any easier way to solve the problem? Did I miss something?

Comment: Is $F$ continuous at $P_1$?

Comment: @user251257 no such restriction.

Comment: then it is wrong. Take $F(x) = 1$ for $x\ne 0$, $F(0)=0$, $P_1=0$, $\Delta = 1/2$. Then you won't find such a $P_2$.

Comment: @user251257 does it mean that only **continuous** functions (at least, at the $P_1$) could be approximated in a way I described?

Comment: yes. ${}{}{}{}{}$